# Environment variables are not set when redirect echo through a pipeline at a function

Tags: shell, linux-mint, process-substitution

This command:

```
echo '18' | source meta-cmf-raspberrypi/setup-environment
```

Not set the environment variables as instead happened with a simply:

```
source meta-cmf-raspberrypi/setup-environment
```

With "18" in input.
The question at link: [Environment variables are not set when my function is called in a pipeline](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134735)

Not solve my problem because i have try:

```
echo '18' > >(source meta-cmf-raspberrypi/setup-environment)
```

Without success.
How do I solve the problem?

Comment: How does `meta-cmf-raspberrypi/setup-environment` look like?

Comment: https://wiki.rdkcentral.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=71011616

Comment: Hmm, where exactly is the contents of `setup-environment` shown?

Comment: it doesn't matter where the command meta-cmf-raspberrypi/setup-environment comes from.

Comment: It does, form the webpage, I can see that `setup-environment` triggers a user input/ prompt. This is a very different problem. Please update the question accordingly for more clarity.

Comment: Is not necessary understand setup environment. The answer below solve my problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Environment variables are not set when my function is called in a pipeline](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134735/environment-variables-are-not-set-when-my-function-is-called-in-a-pipeline)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the pipeline, the script is being sourced in a separate environment. Likewise in the process substitution example. This means that variables set in the script are set in a child environment to the calling shell. Changes in a child environment can never propagate to the parent environment.

You could solve this in two ways, avoiding sourcing the script in a separate environment.

The first way would work in a shell that understand "here-strings":

```
source meta-cmf-raspberrypi/setup-environment <<<18
```

The second way is to use a standard here-document:

```
source meta-cmf-raspberrypi/setup-environment <<END_INPUT
18
END_INPUT
```

In both variations, the script is sourced in the current environment, with its input redirected from the here-string/here-document.

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly!

Comment: @RiccardoLaMarca instead of here-docs or here-strings (which will use a temporary file in bash, zsh and other shells), you could use a process substitution: `source script < <(echo 18)`

Comment: Thanks also more mosvy